# ribbon xml combobox - return to default after choice * not able to choose2x subesequently

Tags: excel

I would like to reset the combobox after use but i always fail
the myRibbon.Invalidate fails also
Any assistance is welcome  THX

```
 <comboBox id="MyCombo2" 
                        label="Folders" 
                        sizeString="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" 
                      getItemCount="GetItemCount"
                      getItemLabel="GetItemLabel"
                      getSelectedItemIndex="GetSelectedItem"
                  
                       onChange="FolderBox_OnChange" >    
                            <item id="ItemCopyFolder2"   
label="Copy_Folder"      imageMso="CopyToFolder"/>
                            <item id="ItemMoveFolder2"   label="Move_Folder"       i  mageMso="MoveToFolder" /> 
                            <item id="ItemVeleteFolder2" label="Delete_Folder"  imageMso="HeaderFooterClose" /> 
</comboBox> 

Ln 129, Col 23: The 'getSelectedItemIndex' attribute is not declared


Sub GetSelectedItemIndex(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Index)
'***** Return selected item for drpTest2 based on value stored in giIndex
    returnedVal = -1
End Sub

'Callback for DropDown GetItemCount
Sub GetItemCount(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef count)
  'Tell the ribbon to show 4 items in the dropdown
  count = 4
End Sub

'Callback for DropDown GetItemLabel
Sub GetItemLabel(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, Index As Integer, ByRef label)
  'This procedure fires once for each item in the dropdown. Index is _
   received as 0, 1, 2, etc. and label is returned.
  label = Choose(Index + 1, "Select from list", "CopyToFolder", "MoveToFolder", "DeleteFolder")
End Sub
--- tried also
Sub GetSelectedItem(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = 1   '***** To select the item with index 1,
                      '***** replace with code to select the desired item
End Sub
```

reading
yoy selct the item and a macro is processed. I would lite to select and process the same item choise again for a secondor third time.
Eventually  retunr automatically to the very first one 'Select from the list'